# c++ remove custom object from vector : std::remove_if': no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

In my project there is a vector

```
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MovingEntity>>gameObjects;
```

Which I want to delete elements from if they meet the criteria.

Method to delete elements:

```
void GameWorld::catchBees()
{
    auto q = std::remove_if(bees.begin(), bees.end(), beeToClose);
    bees.erase(q);
}
```

Method beeToClose:

```
bool GameWorld::beeToClose( const MovingEntity & bee)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Beekeeper> keeper = std::static_pointer_cast<Beekeeper>(m_beekeeper);
    if (bee.getConstPosition().distanceTo(m_beekeeper->getPosition()) > keeper->getCatchDistance())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I try to compile the code I get some errors which I tried to understand:

> 'GameWorld::beeToClose': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a
>   pointer

Not sure why this message is given

> 'std::remove_if': no matching overloaded function found

I did not declare beeToClose right?

> 'q': cannot be used before it is initialized  SDLFramework

q is not initialized because:

```
std::remove_if(bees.begin(), bees.end(), beeToClose);
```

does not run correct?

How can I remove a std::shared_ptr correctly from a vector correctly when meeting some criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for forming a pointer to member function is `&ClassName::FunctionName`. So you need `&GameWorld::beeToClose` for a pointer to the `beeToClose` member function. In your case, you should use a lambda from which you call that function

```
auto q = std::remove_if(bees.begin(), bees.end(),
                    [&](shared_ptr<MovingEntity> const& bee){ return beeToClose(bee); });
```

Also, you're using the wrong [`vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) overload, you want the one that erases a range of elements, not the one that erases a single element.

```
bees.erase(q, bees.end());
```

Comment: Really for remove if, just use `[&]`.

Comment: @Yakk Fine, have it your way :) I linked to the lambda documentation, so the OP can pick his favorite capture.

Answer (score 2):

The `vector` contains `std::shared_ptr<MovingEntity>` elements, so `beeToClose()` needs to accept a `const std::shared_ptr<MovingEntity> &` parameter as input, not a `const MovingEntity &` parameter.  Also, `beeToClose()` appears to be a non-static class method that accesses a non-static class member (`m_beekeeper`), so you can't just pass `beeToClose()` directly to `std::remove_if()` as it does not have access to the calling object's `this` pointer, but you can wrap it in a lambda to capture the `this` pointer.

Try this:

```
void GameWorld::catchBees()
{
    auto q = std::remove_if(bees.begin(), bees.end(),
        [this](const const std::shared_ptr<MovingEntity> &bee) {
            return this->beeToClose(bee);
        }
    );
    bees.erase(q, bees.end());
}

bool GameWorld::beeToClose(const std::shared_ptr<MovingEntity> &bee)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Beekeeper> keeper = std::static_pointer_cast<Beekeeper>(m_beekeeper);
    return (bee->getConstPosition().distanceTo(m_beekeeper->getPosition()) > keeper->getCatchDistance());
}
```

You might also consider moving the distance calculation into `Beekeeper` instead:

```
bool GameWorld::beeToClose(const std::shared_ptr<MovingEntity> &bee)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Beekeeper> keeper = std::static_pointer_cast<Beekeeper>(m_beekeeper);
    return !keeper->isInCatchDistance(bee);
}

bool Beekeeper::isInCatchDistance(const std::shared_ptr<MovingEntity> &bee)
{
    return (bee->getConstPosition().distanceTo(getPosition()) <= getCatchDistance());
}
```